# Distribute updatable Help Wiki

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

We are going to port our chm based help to a mediawiki implementation.
As long as this is read only on our customer's site everything will be fine.
But our customer wants to edit his own copy of our product's wiki.
Clearly this presents us with a problem:
How can we distribute and merge our own wiki changes to our customer's wikis?
We can't update every customer's wiki by hand.

Does mediawiki address distribution and merging (automated/semi automated) of changes?

Hosting a centralized wiki for all customers is not an option for several reasons.

Comment: Should consider interwiki transclusion. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgEnableScaryTranscluding

Answer (score 1):

MediaWiki supports Sections, so you could either define your help text in a specially named section, or require the customer to restrict their edits to a specific section name.

I don't know whether MediaWiki and its API supports section-specific export or import, but a bot which performs the updates could certainly support them.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking a bit outside of the box, a git like system that supports octupus merge may be handy. Also, if the help util is a smart client it could call REST apis to update stuff on the master wiki.